# Can't locate new.pm in @INC

Tags: perl

I tried to run a perl script inside my other shell script but I have faced the following snag:

> Can't locate new.pm in @INC (@INC contains:  /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl

I have specifically set the path where the additional local perl script, i.e,  "new.pm" in my Perl script (test.pl) but the error still appears. (perl -V) shows the path of  my local Perl. I have further also set the the path of my "new.pm" in my profile file using the command "PERL5LIB".

However, when I run the script on a command line as:

```
./test.pl
```

it does work like a charm.

PS. The she-bang line is properly set.
PSS. Platform: linux, OS_vers=2.6.32-5-amd64

Comment: Are you using "use lib $PATH;" ?

Comment: How are you invoking `test.pl` in the shell script (`perl ./test.pl` or `./test.pl`)? What does `which perl` give you inside the shell script?

Comment: Your question reads "It doesn't work, but I did everything correctly!" ("I have specifically set the path where the additional local perl script") Perhaps you shouldn't be so sure of that?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments.  I invok both as (perl ./test.pl and also test as ./test.pl inside my script (test.pl)). "which perl" does give me the correct path to perl when I run it inside the shell script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, but I don't think setting the path is one of them. If "new.pm" is in the `/my/lib` directory, try any of these:

```
perl -I/my/lib script-that-calls-new.pl
```

or

```
use lib '/my/lib'; ## add this before "use new;"
```

or

```
BEGIN { push @INC, '/my/lib'; }; ## same as "use lib" example
```

or

```
export PERL5LIB=/my/lib:$PERL5LIB
```

The path tells your shell where to look for executables. The examples above all tell perl where to find libraries.